# google play how to choose apk to publish

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I just create a new app in google play services and is in Draft mode.

I have uploaded new APK file with version 1, but I upload this to configure my in-app billing produts. The APK version 1 is not the one I want to publish.

My question is if I upload a new version 2 when I publish my app the users on Google play store only see this last one?

I can't delete APK, right? How can I choose the APK to publish.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just how you uploaded the APK for version 1 (By clicking "Upload new APK to Production"), you can upload the APK for version 2 and it will override the earlier version

Comment: Thx a lot HipHopDroid. Ok, can be only one apk at a time. I'd like to vote in your answer but I don't have enought reputation :)